# Passing a function argument into another function

Tags: javascript, debugging

I need to pass a function argument into another function, how would you achieve that? ex:

```
function one(nextFunction) {
    nextFunction()
}

function listener(myFunction) {
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", one(myFunction);
}

listener(theFunction);


function theFunction() {

alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance this doesn't answer my question...

Comment: It should. You need to do exactly what's described in the canonical Q/A there, and your code will work

Comment: I want the function in the event listener "one" to inherit the argument of the listener function.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm sorry but I can't find what I'm looking for... Could you reopen the thread ?

Comment: It is a duplicate of the canonical Q/A. You need to pass a function to `addEventListener` which, when called, invokes `one` with the argument you want, as shown in numerous places in the linked Q/A.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes but I'm using removeEventListener later on in the code and can't have an anonymous function in my listener.

Comment: Then assign the function to a variable so you can remove it later, before passing to `addEventListener`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Maybe I'm just dumb, sorry to spam in here but just don't understand. Could you translate my code here into an example please ?